# How to use a StringIO() object as the program's stdin to send a string to an input statement,

Tags: python, input, io, sys, stringio

I would like be able to reroute the stdin of my program to  a StringIO() object so that I can simulate user response to an input statement.

```
newstdin = StringIO()
sys.stdin = newstdin
newstdin.write("hey")
newstdin.seek(0)

response = input()
print(response)
```

My code works when a response is already in the StringIO() object however if there isn't anything, it immediately raises a EOF error instead of waiting for a response like it would if set to the normal sys.stdin. How can I do this so that the input() statement waits for a response to be written to the StringIO() object (this will be done in a separate thread). Thanks!

Comment: Instead of messing with fds, can't you extract the `response = input()` part and instead do `response = your_fixture()`? I.e. factoring away `input()` when you're testing (if that's what you're doing).

Comment: Sorry, should probably have mentioned this in the question; I am currently working on a IDE and want to be able to run code and have the output inserted into a Tkinter textbox. I have the code set up to insert the stdout of what is being run, but I also want to allow users to put input() statements into their code and type the input into a Tkinter Entry widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, the way I have decided to do it is with this:

```
accinput = input

def input(prompt=None):
    if prompt:
        print(prompt)
    while True:
        try:
            return accinput()
        except EOFError:
            pass
```

You can store the real functionality of input in `accinput` the redefine input to continuously retry to read input from the stdin stringIO() until it doesn't meet an `EOFError`.